# Add a thousands separator to a total with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that sums a column of data in an html table. It does so admirably only I would like to have it put the commas in there that are needed to separate the thousands. Initially, you'll note, there are commas in the numbers being added. So that the function will add them, they are removed. How do I add the commas back in there?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sumOfColumns(tableID, columnIndex, hasHeader) {
        var tot = 0;
        $("#" + tableID + " tr" + (hasHeader ? ":gt(0)" : ""))
          .children("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")
          .each(function() {
              tot += parseInt($(this).html().replace(',', ''));
          });
        return "Total Pounds Entered : " + tot;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `$(this).html().replace(',', '')` shouldn't actually modify the page. Are you sure the commas are being removed in the page?

If it is, this [addCommas function](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html) should do the trick.

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: [I made a *slightly* more foolproof version that checks if nStr is actually a number.](https://github.com/Blacksilver42/website-scripts/blob/master/thousep2.js)

Answer (score 40):

Use `toLocaleString()` 
In your case do:

```
return "Total Pounds Entered : " + tot.toLocaleString();
```

**toLocaleString()** method's syntax looks like:

```
toLocaleString()
toLocaleString(locales)
toLocaleString(locales, options)
```

If your browser can't work with **toLocaleString()** you can try use *locales* argument, for example:

```
var number = 123456.789;

// German uses comma as decimal separator and period for thousands
console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE'));
// → 123.456,789
```

Full documentation available here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: Delightfully simple, but not yet widely supported by browsers. :(

Comment: I can't use it bacause it's dependent on browser locale. Great function otherwise.

Comment: Note: This method is dependant on your locale and might not separate by commas if thats what you need. [See MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: This post may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript
var num = 2046430;
num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2})

Answer (score 21):

This will add thousand separators while retaining the decimal part of a given number:

```
function format(n, sep, decimals) {
    sep = sep || "."; // Default to period as decimal separator
    decimals = decimals || 2; // Default to 2 decimals

    return n.toLocaleString().split(sep)[0]
        + sep
        + n.toFixed(decimals).split(sep)[1];
}

format(4567354.677623); // 4,567,354.68
```

You could also probe for the locale's decimal separator with:

```
var sep = (0).toFixed(1)[1];
```

Comment: toLocaleString only works on Date objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: toLocaleString doesn't add thousand separators. Tested on Firefox 3.5.9 / Snow Leopard.

Comment: @dave1010: You're wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToLocaleString

Comment: @ibz: I guess it depends on your locale. It adds it in my locale (US English.) The question seems to be related to this locale as well. What's your locale?

Comment: toLocaleString() does not add thousands separators and is often identical to toString().

Comment: @danorton: *sigh*... As I mentioned earlier, it depends on _your locale_. But it also seems to depends on the browser. FF6, with English (Canada) locale on Windows adds the comma for me. `(4000).toLocaleString() === "4,000"`. Come over and see for yourself if you still don't believe me :(

Comment: @Ates Yes, it does work in FF depending on locale, but that behavior is non-standard - in Chrome it returns "4000", and IE will return "4,000.00" instead.

Comment: This returns the expected result in Chrome (March 2013) on a US locale comp.  If browser support is there, this is obviously the ideal for most usage, since number separation is very much a locale issue (comma = decimal and group separator = space for, I'm pretty sure, most of the world). However the line 'decimals = decimals || 2;' is an error.  Zero is a reasonable value for the decimals argument but it evaluates to false, so you get 2 instead of 0.

Comment: The simplest and generic function! 

Answer (score 10):

Seems like this is ought to be the approved answer...

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(count)
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: Thx for this answer - should have more upvotes!
Compatiblity is alsop good, even IE can handle this (partial) ;)

Comment: when I type number like "71500" in input and tried to format it as it type, it stuck in "7.150". It couldn't format big number I think or there's another setup or something idk.

Comment: @Fahmi please provide your syntax.  It sounds like you're not using 'en-US' , but I can't help without seeing your code.

Comment: @chad steele hi I apologize for that, I used input number component from ant design vue to format the number in the input field, I think the component just ruined it or something. I use 'id-ID' locale or 'en-GB'. I fixed it by not using the component . sorry

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
</script>
```

---

Use:

```
numberWithCommas(200000);
```

==> 200,000

Answer (score 3):

I got somewhere with the following method:

```
var value = 123456789.9876543 // i.e. some decimal number

var num2 = value.toString().split('.');
var thousands = num2[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g).join(',');
var decimals = (num2[1]) ? '.'+num2[1] : '';

var answer =  thousands.split('').reverse().join('')+decimals;
```

Using split-reverse-join is a sneaky way of working from the back of the string to the front, in groups of 3. There may be an easier way to do that, but it felt intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an uber old post and has good answers, BUT if anyone is interested, there is a jQuery plugin which simplifies number formatting (thousands formatting, number of decimal places, custom thousands separator, etc) by making an include and a simple call.
Has lots of features and documentation is enough. 
It's called [jQuery Number](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number).

You just include it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.number.min.js"></script>
```

And then use it:

On an automatic formatting HTML input: `$('input.number').number( true, 2 );`

or

On a JS call: `$.number( 5020.2364, 2 ); // Outputs: 5,020.24`

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

```
// 2056776401.50 = 2,056,776,401.50
function humanizeNumber(n) {
  n = n.toString()
  while (true) {
    var n2 = n.replace(/(\d)(\d{3})($|,|\.)/g, '$1,$2$3')
    if (n == n2) break
    n = n2
  }
  return n
}
```

Or, in CoffeeScript:

```
# 2056776401.50 = 2,056,776,401.50
humanizeNumber = (n) ->
  n = n.toString()
  while true
    n2 = n.replace /(\d)(\d{3})($|,|\.)/g, '$1,$2$3'
    if n == n2 then break else n = n2
  n
```

Comment: this does not handle decimals well, it convert 12001234.00023123 to 12,001,234.00,023,123 and it should be 12,001,234.00023123

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
function group1k(s) {
    return (""+s)
        .replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})(\d{3})$/  ,"$1 $2 $3" )
        .replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})$/         ,"$1 $2"    )
        .replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})(\d{3})\./ ,"$1 $2 $3.")
        .replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})\./        ,"$1 $2."   )
    ;
}
```

It's a quick solution for anything under 999.999.999, which is usually enough. I know the drawbacks and I'm not saying this is the ultimate weapon - but it's just as fast as the others above and I find this one more readable.  If you don't need decimals you can simplify it even more:

```
function group1k(s) {
    return (""+s)
        .replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})(\d{3})$/ ,"$1 $2 $3")
        .replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})$/        ,"$1 $2"   )
    ;
}
```

Isn't it handy.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the working Example:

```
 $("#estimated-amount-due .content").html("$" + miniCartTotal.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
```

This line is sufficient, it works for me. Check the complete code below. Let me know if it works fine for you too.

```
$(".action.showcart").on('click', function() {
    var miniCartTotal = $("#estimated-subtotal .price").html();
    var miniCartTotalString = miniCartTotal.replace(/\$/g, '');
    var miniCartTotalString = miniCartTotalString.replace(/,/g, ''); 
    var configValue = 5; 

    miniCartTotal = parseFloat(miniCartTotalString) + configValue;
    console.log("updated value " + miniCartTotal);

    $("#estimated-amount-due .content").html("$" + miniCartTotal.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

best and simple way to format the number is to use java-script function

```
var numberToformat = 1000000000
//add locality here, eg: if you need English currency add 'en' and if you need Danish currency format then use 'da-DA'.
var locality = 'en-EN';
numberToformat = numberToformat.toLocaleString(locality , { 
minimumFractionDigits: 4 })
document.write(numberToformat);
```

for more information click [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/tolocalestring-number)

Answer (score -1):

a recursive solution:

```
function thousands(amount) {
  if( /\d{3}\d+/.test(amount) ) {
    return thousands(amount.replace(/(\d{3}?)(,|$)/, ',$&'));
  }
  return amount;
}
```

another split solution:

```
function thousands (amount) {
  return amount
    // reverse string
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('')
    // grouping starting by units
    .replace(/\d{3}/g, '$&,')
    // reverse string again
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('');
}
```

Comment: This does not work btw. It adds commas in front of numbers, for example 456 becomes ",456".