# Simple way to format a number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting

I'm trying to work with jQuery's slider plugin and it works great, only I need to format the output into a readable number, with commas such as 30,402,424 as opposed to 30402424.

I know it's possible with javascript but the only ways I've found are very long winded. I've created a fiddle so you can see what I mean...

http://jsfiddle.net/EX5U7/

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646385/add-a-thousands-separator-to-a-total-with-javascript-or-jquery - every correct answer below implements @dave1010's solution from the linked question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Javascript itself does not have support for formatting the numbers as you need, but with some googling I found the following familiar solution that I have used in the past, somewhat revised for better code quality.

```
function addCommas(numberString) {
  numberString += '';
  var x = numberString.split('.'),
      x1 = x[0],
      x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '',
      rgxp = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

  while (rgxp.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgxp, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }

  return x1 + x2;
}
```

Source: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EX5U7/8/

---

Here's another solution, which implements PHP's `number_format` function in Javascript, allowing you to do even more than just blatantly add commas every 3 numbers:

```
function number_format (number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        s = '',
        toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
        };
    // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
    s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
}
```

Usage: `number_format(123456.789, 2, '.', ',');` results in `123,456.79`

Source: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EX5U7/10/

Comment: Include the relevant parts of the linked source in your answer, trailed by a correct reference. All answers at Stack Overflow should be understandable without following the links.

Comment: Thank you for the note, Rob. Haven't really answered too many questions here yet! I will correct my answer now. :)

Comment: Added another, more advanced example that might be of use.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following [addCommas](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormat.html) method :

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/EX5U7/1/

Answer (score 0):

consider using accounting.js. It is a tiny JavaScript library for number, money and currency formatting

http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp.

```
ui.value = (ui.value).toString().split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g,"$1,").split("").reverse("").join("")
```

Comment: Solution is flawed. Allows numbers such as £275,579,809,0 which is obviously incorrect. Should be £2,755,798,090

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate.

But for your information, the solution provided in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646385/add-a-thousands-separator-to-a-total-with-javascript-or-jquery) allowed me to edit your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EX5U7/4/)

```
$(function() {
         $( "#slider" ).slider({
             value:100,
             min: 0,
             max: 5000000000,
             step: 1,
             slide: function( event, ui ) {
                 $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + addCommas(ui.value) );
             }
         });
         $( "#amount" ).val( "£" + addCommas($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )));
     });

function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function formatNumber(n){
    n += '';
    x = n.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

don't remember from where I got this but have used it here: https://github.com/amantur/jquery.ui.counter