# jQuery, change separator to dot and divide two selected numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, separator, divide

```
var result = parseFloat($('.lot2').text()) / parseFloat($('span.Price').text());
$('.result').text(result);
});
```

How can I convert selected values from comma separated values to dot separated values? There is this function str.replace, but I don't know how to put it in the function.

Comment: what is your result??

Comment: @flzen - No response from your side

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You are definitely right, I must have cut off the last sentence for some accidental reason. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I convert selected values from comma separated values to dot separated values?

From that, I take it that the values you get from `$('.lot2').text()` and `$('span.Price').text()` will use `,` as the decimal point rather than `.` (as is the case in some locales). I assume that you may also have `.` as a thousands separator in there.

If that's what you mean, then you need to do the `,` => `.` conversion, remove the `.` thousands separator, then parse the result, then do `.` => `,` conversion on the resulting value (and possibly add the `.` thousands separator). Here it is with each step separate for clarity:

```
// Get lot 2
var lot2 = $('.lot2').text();
// Remove all `.` thousands separators, replace the one `,` decimal separator with `.`
lot2 = lot2.replace(/\./g, '').replace(",", ".");
// Same with price
var price = $('span.Price').text().replace(/\./g, '').replace(",", ".");
// Parse them and get the result
var result = parseFloat(lot2) / parseFloat(price);
// Replace the `.` decimal separator with `,`
result = String(result).replace(".", ",");
// Show result
$('.result').text(result);
```

If you want to add `.` thousands separators in there, [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646385/add-a-thousands-separator-to-a-total-with-javascript-or-jquery) (and several others here on SO) show how to do that, just use `.` rather than `,`.

Since this is likely to come up repeatedly in your code, you probably want to put both functions (locale form => JavaScript form, JavaScript form => locale form) into functions you can reuse.

Comment: Works like a charm and was understandable for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following snippet:

```
var result = parseFloat($('.lot2').text()) / parseFloat($('span.Price').text());
$('.result').text(result.toString().replace('.', ','));
```

A fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/moon9nve/

And more information on the replace function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace